# UITextField does not show text out of bounds correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to have a `UITextField` that has the behaviour like this with the same fontsize:

[image]

But when I enter the same `min fontsize` as the `original fontsize` I get this behaviour:

[image]

What causes this behaviour and how do I solve that?

I do not want to resize the font. So adjusting the fontsize **won't work**

Comment: someone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: The downvote is probably because a standard UITextField without any additional settings does exactly what you seem to want: to scroll the text without resizing the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. AFAIK, it can't be done. But, you could write your own custom control to do this. I would start by dropping a label on top and take keyboard input to set the contents of the label.

Here's the code that should do the trick. You need to put your label in another view so it clips the text as it's being adjusted.

```
- (IBAction)field1_editing_changed:(id)sender {
NSString *text = self.field1.text;


NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:text
 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.field1.font}];

CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];

CGFloat padding = 5;
CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
width += 2*padding;
CGRect frame = self.field1.frame;
if (width > frame.size.width)
    frame.origin.x -= width - frame.size.width;

frame.origin.y += 30; // I added this so you could see the label appear below the field (for testing only)
frame.origin.x += padding;
frame.size.width = width;
NSLog(@"%g, %g, %g, %g", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
self.label1.frame = frame;
self.label1.text = self.field1.text;
self.label1.font = self.field1.font;
```

}

Comment: why wouldn't I care about scrolling the text? that's the entire trick right?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. The same trick would apply but you would have to adjust the label size and have it clipped by a view. I'm trying out some code to see if I can get it working.

Comment: BTW - It appears to work if you use a smaller font. But, if you want bigger fonts, then the code example above should do the trick. All of that could be wrapped in a class of its own if you like. I extend UIButtons all the time when I want to use similar functionally in an app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a setting wrong. By default, as you type on a `UITextField` it will keep the curser visible at the last entered character as the first example you provided does but with no change to font size. The shrinking behavior will only occur if you set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to YES. Try deleting the `minimumFontSize` and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` settings.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` has a property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, see [UITextField Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UItextfield_Class/Reference/UItextfield.html).

You can set a big enough default font size and let the control reduce the text to fit the width. The actual font size will be between `minimumFontSize` and the size setting of `font`.

Comment: The thing is however that I don't want the font to shrink, but I want to scroll the text the user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to UILable, UITextField has a property 
"adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth"
You can try to set this to YES